# How to change session expire time for specific user role in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to force my subscriber to re-login every 15 minutes
I researched and end up with this code.
This will force log out for any user. But I want to apply to the subscriber role only

```
add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', 'my_expiration_filter', 99, 3);
function my_expiration_filter($seconds, $user_id, $remember){

//if "remember me" is checked;
if ( $remember ) {
    //WP defaults to 2 weeks;
    $expiration = 14*24*60*60; //UPDATE HERE;
} else {
    //WP defaults to 48 hrs/2 days;
    $expiration = 2*24*60*60; //UPDATE HERE;
}

//http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem
if ( PHP_INT_MAX - time() < $expiration ) {
    //Fix to a little bit earlier!
    $expiration =  PHP_INT_MAX - time() - 5;
}

return $expiration;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code -

```
    add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', 'my_expiration_filter', 99, 3);
    function my_expiration_filter($seconds, $user_id, $remember){
    
     $user = wp_get_current_user();
     if ( in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {

       //if "remember me" is checked;
       if ( $remember ) {
        //WP defaults to 2 weeks;
        $expiration = 14*24*60*60; //UPDATE HERE;
       } else {
        //WP defaults to 48 hrs/2 days;
        $expiration = 2*24*60*60; //UPDATE HERE;
       }
    
       //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem
       if ( PHP_INT_MAX - time() < $expiration ) {
        //Fix to a little bit earlier!
        $expiration =  PHP_INT_MAX - time() - 5;
       }
    
       return $expiration;
     }
   }
```